# how i get to know is my class diagram in perfect or not where i am quit clear in how i am going to code

Tags: uml

I have done a web site project in PHP using mySQL at school, which was not object oriented but that was in a manner on which I want to display my content. Then I changed the same project into object orientated classes where I use same CRUD queries in functions of that classes and they interact with a DBWrapper class. Or can say, I just cut the php content and pasted it into the functions and and call that functionality through object. that all was done without documentation. But now i am making a project in .net with documentation how ever its a web based app actually and i have the idea of getting data from database trough queries and o of course c# is different but CRUD is something which is similar in any language. so as i had decide first this thing will display and from thing the next this thing will display etc. about codding than how should i know my class diagram is the same as what i am getting and what that actually is. because i will connect both classes as i wnt to display . and plus is Do we write object of other class as an attribute of second class if that is going to use in it.

Comment: The question is not clear. If you want to know how to create a class diagram I would suggest you first do some research and come back with specific questions.

Comment: no i don't want to know how to create a class diagram. i wanted to know either created class diagram is right or not. because in coding when i start the code i always have more classes to code than i draw in class diagram. where these classes are in my mind that these should be included but someone who have batter concepts than me ask me that you are not right such things are not the part of class diagram. hope this will be understandable

Answer (score 0):

Most class diagrams I've seen and made include only the business model entities. Most of the time UML diagrams are used to communicate and document the workings of the system. I like to think of them as pseudo-code.

Please refer to this other question as well: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190429/what-classes-to-put-exactly-in-a-class-diagram

However, if you feel your implementation ended up with a lot of helper classes then it's probably good to review your system's structure to make sure you are coding "object oriented". Actually making the class diagram is supposed to help you realize what you can improve.

I suggest you also take a look at design patterns. This link might be useful, as you mention experience with C# http://www.dotnettricks.com/learn/designpatterns